# How to add two different apple developer accounts to the same project?

Tags: xcode, apple-developer

I have a project that uses my company's apple developer account, But it's not live yet, just couple TestFlight versions. 
Now the client wants to go live using their own apple developer account.

What is the perfect solution fo this case? Can I have the same project but linked to two different apple accounts?

I have tried making two different configuration files (`DebugClient & ReleaseClient`), new schemes and created a new apple id (bundle identifier) on the clients account. Then I changed `Development Team` for (`DebugClient & ReleaseClient`) to be client's account.

But the app crashes with this error `dyld__abort_with_payload:`

**Note:** The app uses `CocoaPods`

Comment: "Can I have the same project but linked to two different apple accounts?"  No.

Comment: Even with two different schemes? the first account will be just for testing with different app id.

Comment: You don't set the signing identity in the scheme, it's within the project settings.  Why do you need both assigned at the same time?

Comment: You are right, I set the signing identity for each configuration in build settings, and the scheme just uses the new scheme.

Comment: @trojanfoe The company wants to have their own version just for testing/development.